# Could not load file or assembly 'Bunifu_UI_v1.5.3' (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)

Tags: bunifu

I've been getting this error in one of my Visual Studio 2017 projects for a while now:

```
'SploitBase UI©.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SploitBase UI©.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Angus\Desktop\SploitBase UI©\SploitBase UI©\bin\Debug\SploitBase UI©.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'SploitBase UI©.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SploitBase UI©.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualBasic\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SploitBase UI©.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SploitBase UI©.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SploitBase UI©.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SploitBase UI©.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SploitBase UI©.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SploitBase UI©.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SploitBase UI©.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SploitBase UI©.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SploitBase UI©.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SploitBase UI©.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SploitBase UI©.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SploitBase UI©.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SploitBase UI©.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SploitBase UI©.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Remoting\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Remoting.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileLoadException' in SploitBase UI©.exe
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in SploitBase UI©.exe
An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Could not load file or assembly 'Bunifu_UI_v1.5.3, Version=1.5.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)

The program '[5012] SploitBase UI©.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

I've re-downloaded the Bunifu DLL, and re-added it to Toolbox and References, but still doesn't seem to make a difference.

> The program also enters 'Break mode' when I Start it, and whenever I start the program from

```
C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\SploitBase UI©\SploitBase UI©\bin\Debug
```

> it says 'This program is not responding'.

Comment: Not get your response, would you please share us the latest information in your side? As you get this error during debugging, what about the result if you just run your app using "start without debugging"? How did you refer to this dll file in your side? Or you could check that whether you could find it in your project output path or matched version.

Answer (score 1):

By default 'Just my code' option is enabled and with this options ON, VS will skip loading symbols for optimized dll-s. You can disable 'Just My Code' by unchecking this option in Debug->Options->Debugging->General:

[image]

Also, try to uncheck optimize code, under project properties:

[image]

Comment: Hello, @Fletch Zhou-MSFT I will try this issue soon! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Bunifu Dll is not signed with a strong keyname, that is mistake made during deployment, what you need to do therefore is avoid signing your software - *a temporary solution*. A request has been submitted to the company to sign their assemblies. See below on how to disable - [ leave unchecked ].

[image: Disabling strong keyname signing]

Comment: Hello, try their latest build 1.5.4, DLL have been signed.