# Could not load file or assembly exception HRResult: 0x80131044

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project that I inherited from someone else who is no longer available to assist.

During execution of the application I get the following error

```
    ************** Exception Text **************
    System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Jasper.SharedCode, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)
    File name: 'Jasper.SharedCode, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
       at SysUserInterfaceUtil.GridPopUpMenu.DoExport(String fileName, ExportTypes exportType)
       at SysUserInterfaceUtil.GridPopUpMenu.exportXML_ItemClick(Object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
       at DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItem.OnClick(BarItemLink link)
       at DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItem.OnClick(BarItemLink link)
       at DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItemLink.OnLinkClick()
       at DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItemLink.OnLinkAction(BarLinkAction action, Object actionArgs)
       at DevExpress.XtraBars.ViewInfo.BarSelectionInfo.UnPressLink(BarItemLink link)
       at DevExpress.XtraBars.Controls.CustomLinksControl.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at DevExpress.XtraBars.Controls.CustomControl.WndProc(Message& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

From what I can tell though, SysUserInterfaceUtil makes no reference to Jasper.SharedCode.
How do I resolve this issue? Do I need to sign Jasper.SharedCode? Is there a way to resolve this without signing Jasper.SharedCode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Forms Error: "A strongly-named assembly is required"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290980/windows-forms-error-a-strongly-named-assembly-is-required)

Comment: If the library is not being used, you could remove it from the project's references.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48835342/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-bunifu-ui-v1-5-3-exception-from-hresult-0x80

Comment: You have an old copy of Jasper.SharedCode.dll, it does not yet have a strong name.  But the program was built with another version of it that did have a strong name.  The mismatch is fatal.  Just make sure that the old copy is updated correctly, use Fuslogvw.exe if you have no idea where it came from.

Answer (score 2):

If the library is indeed used by some other library you are referencing, the problem could be that strong name bypassing is deactivated. Strong names are bypassed since .NET 3.5.

Check these settings in the registry (depending on your operating system bitness):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework
```

If the Key `AllowStrongNameBypass` exists with a value of `0`, set the value to `1`.

More information on strong name bypassing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-disable-the-strong-name-bypass-feature

Comment: Thank you for your reply, neither of those settings exist in my registry.