# Could not load file or assembly Tesseract. A strongly-named assembly is required

Tags: c#, tesseract, strongname

I was using Tesseract 3.0.2 with the same 3.0.2 tesdata pack

but some of the word in the document uploaded by client are not that readable, so I tried to update the version of Tesseract.

I install Tesseract 4.1.1 from Nuget package and now I am getting the below error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Tesseract, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51285151/2791540)

Comment: no success, still I want to sign but unable to

Comment: Make sure you do a clean build to remove all the intermediate obj files.  If you still get errors read the release notes here : https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ReleaseNotes.html